# Ember.js View get value of implicit iterator in context

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to reference the value of the implicit iterator `{{.}}` from inside an `Ember.View`?

e.g.

**View Template**

```
{{#each simple_old_array_of_numbers}}
    {{view App.Subview}}
{{/each}}
```

**View Code**

```
App.Subview = Em.View.extend({
    template_name: 'subview_template',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        //do some logic based on the implicit iterator
        //have tried this.get('.'), but that didn't work
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understand well, but you can do something like

```
{{#each item in simple_old_array_of_numbers}}
  {{view App.Subview itemBinding="item"}}
{{/each}}

App.Subview = Em.View.extend({
  template_name: 'subview_template',
  item: null,
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.get('item'));
  }
});
```

Comment: I had no clue that the handlebars `{{#each}}` could take anything more complex that the array name, thanks! I've learned a new trick :)

Comment: You're welcome :), I think it's ember-related, more than handlebars: see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each